# Multiple templates for Pull Requests on Github

Tags: github, pull-request

According to documentation I had to create a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` folder in `.github` folder.

Then add my `pull_request_first_template` and `pull_request_second_template.md` into `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` folder.

When I try to open a new PR, no templates are being displayed, not speaking of even switching between them.

Seems like templates are not displaying at all. Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer, yes there is a solution to this. However, there are a few steps to make this possible:

1. Create either a `.github/` or `docs/` directory in your root directory.
2. Create a directory inside called `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE`.
3. Create as many templates as you'd like within this directory, let's say `template_one.md` and `template_two.md`.
4. Begin making a pull request and append the URL with: "&template=template_one.md"

My example URL looks like: `https://github.com/<org>/<repo-name>/compare/main...test-branch?template=template_one.md`

[image]

Comment: So realistically, only way to access those is to modify URL? There is no way of choosing Template when opening a PR?

Comment: Why is still after years this is only way to have multiple templates? Why they just don't add a simple dropdown to select the template? Or better yet, allow a config (something like the codeowners) to specify rules for which default template should be used based on what files were touched so that each team having diff folders can have their custom template.

Answer (score 28):

You can create a manual template selection, such that at least developers who open a PR can click on a link to get to their respective template:

1. Assuming you have two templates `group_a_template.md` and `group_b_template.md` under `.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE`
2. Create the default template `.github/pull_request_template.md` with the following content

   ```
   Please go the the `Preview` tab and select the appropriate sub-template:

   * [Group A](?expand=1&template=group_a_template.md)
   * [Group B](?expand=1&template=group_b_template.md)
   ```

In this way, people who open a PR interactively in the UI will first get to the default template and can open their respective target template from the "Preview" view.

Not optimal, but more convenient than patching the URL manually every time you submit a PR.

Comment: that didn't work for me, it is not showing the default template. Is it working for you? Did you do something different ?

Comment: Yes, I'm actively using this setup. The default template should be picked up in any case by new PRs, are you sure the file name is correct?

GitHub will only pick up the template from the default branch, so be sure that you have already merged it to there. Templates in non-default branches are not used.

Comment: What does the `expand=1` query parameter do? Including or excluding it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also wondering, I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. After more tests, it seems that templates below the `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` folder are not selected or even selectable by default, and can only be directly addressed via the URL parameter. The only template selected by default has been `.github/pull_request_template.md`.

Answer (score -1):

I found a more convenient solution for this today. The problem with the current answer(s) is that you either need to create a custom URL, or create an additional template outside of the `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` directory.

The alternative is to use a symlink, like this:

```bash
cd .github
ln -s PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/pull_request_template.md pull_request_template.md
git add pull_request_template.md
git commit -m "Add symlink to default pull request template"
```

Once merged into the default branch, any new pull requests created through github.com will use the linked template.

Comment: How does this solve the issue of not being able to choose a template if you have multiple?